# Sources folder not building in Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

My Swift Playground is linked with an Xcode Project, for error highlighting and stuff. Upon trying a new run, this happened -

```
Playground execution failed:
error: Foo.playground:36:21: error: use of unresolved identifier 'GameScene'
    let scene = GameScene()
                ^~~~~~~~~
```

It was properly defined in Sources, and this had never happened before, so I concluded it was a problem with the Sources folder. And upon running it a second time - it was.

```
Playground execution failed:
error: /var/folders/ff/mh9n4vn14w58hmrbq4235wzm0000gn/T/playground3-a91091..swift:3:8: error: no such module 'Foo_Sources'
import Foo_Sources
         ^
```

That location containing...

```
@_silgen_name ("playground_logger_initialize") func $builtin_logger_initialize ()
@_silgen_name ("playground_log_hidden") func $builtin_log_with_id<T> (_ object : T, _ name : String, _ id : Int, _ sl : Int, _ el : Int, _ sc : Int, _ ec: Int) -> AnyObject
@_silgen_name ("playground_log_scope_entry") func $builtin_log_scope_entry (_ sl : Int, _ el : Int, _ sc : Int, _ ec: Int) -> AnyObject
@_silgen_name ("playground_log_scope_exit") func $builtin_log_scope_exit (_ sl : Int, _ el : Int, _ sc : Int, _ ec: Int) -> AnyObject
@_silgen_name ("playground_log_postprint") func $builtin_postPrint (_ sl : Int, _ el : Int, _ sc : Int, _ ec: Int) -> AnyObject
@_silgen_name ("DVTSendPlaygroundLogData") func $builtin_send_data (_ :  AnyObject!)
$builtin_logger_initialize()
import Foo_Sources
#sourceLocation(file: "Foo.playground", line: 1)
```

I'm honestly stumped. Running it alone without xcode project brings the compile to a standstill, and Cleaning or pressing Clean Build Folder doesn't help either.

This question is being asked on Stack Overflow, [the WWDC Scholars forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/301811#301811), and [the Swift Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/8762zl/sources_folder_not_building_in_swift_playground/).

**EDIT:** Some of the code stripped down... (Not the real code but enough to give an idea of what it looks like)

Main Playground File: (Contents.swift)

```
import UIKit
```

import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0 , y:0, width: 375, height: 667))

    let scene = GameScene()

    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    sceneView.presentScene(scene)

    self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
   }

}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = FooViewController()
```

Main Game Scene: (the one being called, leading me to believe Sources isn't being built)

```
public class GameScene: SKScene {

  public override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
      backgroundColor = .white
  }


}
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Restarting Xcode
- Restarting computer
- Reinstalling Xcode
- Going to `/var/folders/ff/mh9n4vn14w58hmrbq4235wzm0000gn/T` and deleting anything that starts with `playground`
- Using CCleaner to clear all cache
- Running `Clean` in Xcode
- Running `Clean Build Folder` in Xcode
- Manually deleting everything in `Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- Using Git, reverting to the most stable version I could find, and re-running

  - *This actually worked*, so I'm reviewing my changes.

Comment: Just a thought: did you try restarting xcode? Also, can you paste you playground code so someone can try it on their machine?

Comment: I've restarted Xcode, I've _reinstalled_ Xcode, and I don't know how to fix this. I also don't feel comfortable posting the code here, because this is for the WWDC scholarship.

Comment: I don't mean post all the code. Strip it down as far as it will go and still show the problem. Actually, doing that exercise will often reveal the problem to you. So even if you don't want to post any code, stripping it down for your own private viewing is a useful step.